# Typescript: tabBarOptions from createBottomTabNavigator

Tags: typescript, react-native, react-navigation, expo

I was building a react-native app via `expo init` via its 3rd option, which creates basic navigation template in Javascript. 
And recently I was trying out the Typescript with the existing template and try to convert those js code into typescript but cannot figure out why typescript raise errors on tabBarOptions.

The below is the partial code with slightly modifications from original(official) that has nothing to do with the type error. The code itself is perfectly runnable and the pattern appears in many SO questions about how to use `tabBarOptions` in `createBottomTabNavigator` correctly.

[image]
[image]

This is the typescript error.
[image]

I also see the issue from github that layouts the component relationship.

https://github.com/react-navigation/tabs/issues/174

As far as I understand based on the link, the error shall not appear. I'm new to typescript so please don't judge me if I misunderstand any concept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The crux of the error is in the line where typescript says that types of property `fontWeight` are incompatible.

`react-navigation-tabs` library accepts only a limited number of possible fontWeight values. You are supplying a correct value, however, Typescript cannot be sure that the content of `tabConfig` is not mutated anywhere, so it treats `fontWeight` as a string.

There are two ways to get around this issue:

1. Move `tabConfig` definition inline:

```
createBottomTabNavigator({
   tabConfig: {
      labelStyle: {
         fontWeight: 'bold'
      }
      // and other props...
   }
})
```

2. Declare tabConfig as immutable. This way Typescript will properly handle types

```
const tabConfig = {
    labelStyle: {
        fontWeight: 'bold'
    }
    // and other props...
} as const; //<--- this `as const` operator does the trick

createBottomTabNavigator({ tabConfig })
```

Comment: Thx a lot! Do you mind elaborating a little bit more about  `Typescript cannot be sure that the content of tabConfig is not mutated anywhere, so it treats fontWeight as a string.` and how does the `as const` works in this case. Any links are appreciated so I can crush the same crux in the future since I still have trouble to read typescript errors.

Comment: and any drawbacks to use `as const` trick so I don't misuse anywhere it in case.

Comment: By default, objects in Javascript can be mutated, there can be property updates. `as const` marks object is readonly, so changing a property would be a compilation error.

Typescript cannot detect that object never changes because it is very expensive operation. This issue contains some more detailed explanation: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/9998